# Auto switch to dark theme and back in apps and browser

Tags: themes, thirdpartyapps, eos6

I have eOS 6 Odin installed.
On Windows I have the auto switch for dark and light themes. Along with this, all the apps that have option for switching between themes also changing their themes accordingly to the system-wide theme.

On eOS we have similar - theme is changing on schedule. But the same apps just know nothing about current system theme state (theme is changing on schedule).

My question: what parameter do applications look at to change their theme (in which file)?

Comment: Some clarification: I mean applications which are primarily distributed for Debian/Ubuntu.
And parameter which I try to find I guess should be in some gnome or gtk config files.

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions that you can apply, see if this this post can serve you,
http://entornosgnulinux.com/2021/09/06/odin-tip-ii-tema-elementary-y-modo-oscuro-para-flatpak-en-elementary-os-odin/

Comment: Welcome to eSE! While this might answer the question, the linked page is in Spanish and may not exist for the full operational time of Odin. Could you [edit] your answer to include the necessary bits from the blog post in English? You can leave the link in place, but be sure to identify it as the source of the answer 

Comment: This instruction gives us method for auto switch themes only for flatpak apps. thanks though!
As was point out by @matigo, some of the actions was also possible due to Elementary Tweaks (not Odin compatible). Odin is now uses its fork Pantheon Tweaks, which have small amount features in comparison to the old Tweaks.